# Why can't I join my friend on Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-network, nintendo-switch

I am playing on mobile (phone) and my friend is playing on a Switch. We both have Minecraft Bedrock Edition, Xbox Live accounts, and added each other on all of these things, but neither of our worlds will show up for either of us even if we invite each other.

We also have the same version of the game, what can we do? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Ask your friend if he has Nintendo Switch Online, as that is the only way to play cross platform on the Nintendo Switch.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has Nintendo Switch Online, one of you should host the game and join through an IP adress. Be wary, not every network allows that. The only way to easily join the other player through Xbox is if they're hosting a Realm.

If your friend doesn't have Nintendo Switch Online he can't play online games. Unfortunately it's paid.

Answer (score -1):

This may be happening because your friend doesn’t have Nintendo Online Play. If he does however the try restarting Minecraft or ask your friend to restart his Nintendo.

Comment: Hello. There's already another answer explaining that Nintendo Online is required. And OP wrote that "even if we invite each other", so this answer really adds nothing new.